# When $N(N(H))=N(H)$, where $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, characteristic-subgroups

Suppose $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ which is a subgroup of $G$.

If $H \lhd G$ or $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N(H)$, then $N(N(H))=N(H)$.

If $H \lhd G$, the result will be obvious. If $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N(H)$, then $H \lhd N(N(H))$ since $N(H) \lhd N(N(H))$. Hence, $N(N(H)) \subset N(H)$ and the result is followed.

Now, my question is under what other conditions $N(N(H))=N(H)$ does hold? That is when $H$ is not normal in $G$ and not characteristic in $N(H)$ but $N(N(H))=N(H)$.

Comment: One example is the $A_5$ inside $A_6$, in the direct product $A_6\times A_5$. Its normalizer is $A_5\times A_5$, and is self-normalizing. This example can be generalized, of course. I do not know of any general condition.

Comment: In nilpotent groups normalizers always grow (in fact, this property characterizes nilpotent groups). Thus, the group should not be nilpotent. Of course, the question still remains.

Comment: Please check “applications” in this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini%27s_argument